# IBM Worklight - Unable to get network signal strength in Android

Tags: java, android, ibm-mobilefirst, telephony

Below is my Java implementation. The idea is to display `myUtilString` in an edit text in order to see the signal strength in a Hybrid android app while in a WL.NativePage, but I get nothing.

I have tested the app on a real device, changing to 2G, 3G and LTE but I don't receive anything. I have implemented a function called `onSignalStrengthsChanged`, but I cant figure out what is wrong.

In LogCat there is nothing of interest; maybe `onSignalStrengthsChanged` never is fired.

```
package com.AndroidShowNativePage;

import android.app.Activity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import android.app.Activity; 
import android.content.Context; 
import android.telephony.gsm.GsmCellLocation; 
import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener; 
import android.telephony.SignalStrength; 
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager; 
import android.telephony.CellLocation; 
import android.webkit.WebView; 

public class HelloNative extends Activity {

    EditText editText = null;
    EditText editText1 = null;
    String myUtilString = "";

    private TelephonyManager tm ;
    private DroidPhoneStateListener listener;
    private GsmCellLocation location;

    public void GSM(Activity activity, WebView view) {
        tm = (TelephonyManager) activity
        .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        listener = new DroidPhoneStateListener(view);
        location = new GsmCellLocation();
        } 

    public void listen() { 
    tm.listen(listener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_SIGNAL_STRENGTHS);
    //TODO 
    //tm.listen(listener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_SIGNAL_STRENGTH); 
    //tm.listen(listener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CELL_LOCATION); 
    //tm.listen(listener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_DATA_ACTIVITY); 
    } 

    public void unlisten() { 
    tm.listen(listener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE);
    } 

    public int getCid() { 
    return location.getCid();
    } 

    public int getLac() { 
    return location.getLac();
    } 

    /* 
    * ???? public int getPsc() { return location.getPsc(); } 
    */ 
    private class DroidPhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {

        private WebView view;

        DroidPhoneStateListener(WebView view) {
        this.view = view;
        } 

        @Override 
        public void onCellLocationChanged(CellLocation location) {
            myUtilString = ( "onCellLocationChanged: " + location.toString());
        // view.loadUrl("javascript:droid.Accelerometer.onUpdate(); 
        } 

        @Override 
        public void onDataConnectionStateChanged(int state, int networkType) {
            myUtilString =( "onDataConnectionStateChanged: " + state + ":" + networkType);
        }

        @Override 
        public void onSignalStrengthsChanged(SignalStrength s) {
        super.onSignalStrengthsChanged(s);
        String r = s.getGsmSignalStrength() + ":" + s.getCdmaDbm() + ":"
        + s.getCdmaEcio() + ":" + s.getEvdoDbm() + ":"
        + s.getEvdoEcio() + ":" + s.getEvdoSnr() + ":"
        + s.getGsmBitErrorRate();
            myUtilString = ("hello Change('" + r.toString()+ "');");
        } 

        @Override 
        public void onSignalStrengthChanged(int asu) {
            myUtilString = ( "onSignalStrengthChanged: " + asu);
        } 

} 




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        String name = getIntent().getStringExtra("nameParam");

        LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
        linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        setContentView(linearLayout);

        TextView textView1 = new TextView(this);
        textView1.setText("Name received from JavaScript :: " + name);

        TextView textView2 = new TextView(this);
        textView2.setText("Enter the phone number");

        editText = new EditText(this);
        editText.setText("1234567890");

        editText1 = new EditText(this);
        editText1.setText("any measure on dBd");

        Button submitButton = new Button(this);
        submitButton.setText("Return to the Web App");
        submitButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String phoneNumber = editText.getText().toString();
                Intent phoneNumberInfo = new Intent();
                phoneNumberInfo.putExtra("phoneNumber", phoneNumber);
                setResult(RESULT_OK, phoneNumberInfo);
                finish();
            }
        });

        Button submitMeasure = new Button(this);
        submitMeasure.setText("Go measure");
        submitMeasure.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                editText1.setText( myUtilString );

            }
        });

        linearLayout.addView(textView1);
        linearLayout.addView(textView2);
        linearLayout.addView(editText);

        linearLayout.addView(submitButton);
        linearLayout.addView(submitMeasure);
        linearLayout.addView(editText1);
    }

}
```

here is LogCat:

```
05-08 12:06:30.140: D/SoftKeyboardDetect(1078): Ignore this event
05-08 12:06:31.190: D/WLDroidGap(1078): Started copying files to local storage...
05-08 12:06:48.800: D/dalvikvm(1078): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 494K, 15% free 3318K/3896K, paused 35ms, total 35ms
05-08 12:06:59.950: D/dalvikvm(1078): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 370K, 16% free 3319K/3908K, paused 34ms, total 34ms
05-08 12:07:10.540: D/WLDroidGap(1078): Finished copying files to local storage...
05-08 12:07:10.550: D/WLDroidGap(1078): no need to check web resource integrity
05-08 12:07:10.690: D/CordovaWebView(1078): >>> loadUrl(file:///data/data/com.AndroidShowNativePage/files/www/skinLoader.html)
05-08 12:07:10.690: D/PluginManager(1078): init()
05-08 12:07:10.730: D/CordovaWebView(1078): >>> loadUrlNow()
05-08 12:07:12.560: D/CordovaActivity(1078): onMessage(onPageStarted,file:///data/data/com.AndroidShowNativePage/files/www/skinLoader.html)
05-08 12:07:14.610: D/CordovaWebViewClient(1078): onPageFinished(file:///data/data/com.AndroidShowNativePage/files/www/skinLoader.html)
05-08 12:07:14.610: D/CordovaActivity(1078): onMessage(onPageFinished,file:///data/data/com.AndroidShowNativePage/files/www/skinLoader.html)
05-08 12:07:16.650: D/CordovaActivity(1078): onMessage(spinner,stop)
05-08 12:07:17.250: D/CordovaActivity(1078): onMessage(spinner,stop)
05-08 12:07:17.260: W/PluginManager(1078): THREAD WARNING: exec() call to App.show blocked the main thread for 21ms. Plugin should use CordovaInterface.getThreadPool().
05-08 12:07:17.400: D/CordovaNetworkManager(1078): Connection Type: 3g
05-08 12:07:17.400: D/CordovaActivity(1078): onMessage(networkconnection,3g)
05-08 12:07:17.420: D/CordovaNetworkManager(1078): Connection Type: 3g
05-08 12:07:17.660: D/dalvikvm(1078): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 458K, 14% free 3365K/3908K, paused 36ms, total 39ms
05-08 12:07:17.710: W/PluginManager(1078): THREAD WARNING: exec() call to Utils.writePref blocked the main thread for 95ms. Plugin should use CordovaInterface.getThreadPool().
05-08 12:07:17.780: W/PluginManager(1078): THREAD WARNING: exec() call to Utils.writePref blocked the main thread for 35ms. Plugin should use CordovaInterface.getThreadPool().
05-08 12:07:17.790: D/CordovaWebView(1078): >>> loadUrl(file:///data/data/com.AndroidShowNativePage/files/www/default/AndroidShowNativePage.html)
05-08 12:07:17.810: D/PluginManager(1078): init()
05-08 12:07:17.810: W/PluginManager(1078): THREAD WARNING: exec() call to Utils.loadSkin blocked the main thread for 29ms. Plugin should use CordovaInterface.getThreadPool().
05-08 12:07:17.820: D/CordovaWebView(1078): >>> loadUrlNow()
05-08 12:07:18.020: D/CordovaActivity(1078): onMessage(onPageStarted,file:///data/data/com.AndroidShowNativePage/files/www/default/AndroidShowNativePage.html)
05-08 12:07:23.320: D/CordovaActivity(1078): onMessage(spinner,stop)
05-08 12:07:23.370: D/CordovaNetworkManager(1078): Connection Type: 3g
05-08 12:07:23.400: D/CordovaNetworkManager(1078): Connection Type: 3g
05-08 12:07:23.400: D/CordovaActivity(1078): onMessage(networkconnection,3g)
05-08 12:07:24.010: D/CordovaWebViewClient(1078): onPageFinished(file:///data/data/com.AndroidShowNativePage/files/www/default/AndroidShowNativePage.html)
05-08 12:07:24.010: D/CordovaActivity(1078): onMessage(onPageFinished,file:///data/data/com.AndroidShowNativePage/files/www/default/AndroidShowNativePage.html)
05-08 12:07:24.240: I/Choreographer(1078): Skipped 32 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-08 12:07:24.440: D/AndroidShowNativePage(1078): wlclient init started
05-08 12:07:24.530: D/AndroidShowNativePage(1078): Read cookies: null
05-08 12:07:24.560: D/AndroidShowNativePage(1078): CookieMgr read cookies: {}
05-08 12:07:24.870: W/AndroidShowNativePage(1078): Your application is using the WL.OptionsMenu API. Note that, if your application targets Android 3.0 (API level 11) or higher, WL.OptionsMenu might have no effect, depending on the device.
05-08 12:07:24.970: W/PluginManager(1078): THREAD WARNING: exec() call to DeviceAuth.getDeviceUUID blocked the main thread for 24ms. Plugin should use CordovaInterface.getThreadPool().
05-08 12:07:25.000: D/AndroidShowNativePage(1078): addDeviceIDHeader deviceIDSuccessCallback
05-08 12:07:25.050: W/PluginManager(1078): THREAD WARNING: exec() call to Utils.writePref blocked the main thread for 21ms. Plugin should use CordovaInterface.getThreadPool().
05-08 12:07:25.080: D/AndroidShowNativePage(1078): connectOnStartup finalizeInit
05-08 12:07:25.190: D/AndroidShowNativePage(1078): before: app init onSuccess
05-08 12:07:25.310: D/AndroidShowNativePage(1078): after: app init onSuccess
05-08 12:07:25.350: D/AndroidShowNativePage(1078): added onPause event handler 
05-08 12:07:25.370: D/AndroidShowNativePage(1078): wlclient init success
05-08 12:26:11.550: D/CordovaActivity(1078): Paused the application!
05-08 12:26:11.550: D/CordovaWebView(1078): Handle the pause
05-08 12:26:11.650: W/PluginManager(1078): THREAD WARNING: exec() call to NativePage.show blocked the main thread for 151ms. Plugin should use CordovaInterface.getThreadPool().
05-08 12:26:12.620: I/Choreographer(1078): Skipped 60 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-08 12:26:13.040: D/AndroidShowNativePage(1078): Flush called
05-08 12:26:17.070: I/Choreographer(1078): Skipped 75 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Comment: by the way Do I need a special permission for this? I mean  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission. SOMETHING ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you get any errors either in Eclipse console or in the LogCat view? Provide the output from LogCat, that should help. Edit the question with this information.

The following permission needs to be added to AndroidManifest.xml as well:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />`

**Edit:**
There is also the following tutorial to get signal strength: http://www.firstdroid.com/2010/05/12/get-provider-gsm-signal-strength/

I've followed it, and it worked for me in the Android emulator.
This is my Java implementation:

```
package com.testapp;

import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
import android.telephony.SignalStrength;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class HelloNative extends Activity {

    TelephonyManager        tm;
    MyPhoneStateListener    MyListener;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        MyListener   = new MyPhoneStateListener();
        tm = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        tm.listen(MyListener ,PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_SIGNAL_STRENGTHS);

        LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
        linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        setContentView(linearLayout);

        Button submitButton = new Button(this);
        submitButton.setText("Return to the Web App");
        submitButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                setResult(RESULT_OK);
                finish();
            };
        });

        linearLayout.addView(submitButton);
    }

    private class MyPhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener
    {
      /* Get the Signal strength from the provider, each time there is an update */
      @Override
      public void onSignalStrengthsChanged(SignalStrength signalStrength)
      {
         super.onSignalStrengthsChanged(signalStrength);
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Signal strength is: "
            + String.valueOf(signalStrength.getGsmSignalStrength()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }

    };

}
```

Comment: i have added this permission when i started the project

Comment: Edit your question with the output from LogCat.

Comment: i hit the button to print changing the network state with F8 ? nothing happens

Comment: The log doesn't show anything interesting. What is the scenario? is this is Worklight HYBRID app that you use WL.NativePage.show to open a native activity and try to run in it your Java code?

Comment: Thanks @Idan Thanks!!! I will modify the code to obtain the measurement for 4G and others.