# Closing Worklight App on click based on sim details

Tags: javascript, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

I am developing a IBM Worklight application and I want to check my SIM details before launching my application using below code snippet:

```
function wlCommonInit() {   
    WL.Device.getNetworkInfo(function(networkInfo) {
        var NetInfo = (networkInfo.carrierName).toUpperCase();
        var networkState = (navigator.connection.type).toUpperCase();
        var NetInfo = (networkInfo.carrierName).toUpperCase();
        if (NetInfo.indexOf("ANDROID") == -1) {
            alert("Android Network not available");
            WL.App.close();
        }
        if (networkState == "NONE") {
            alert("Data connection not available");
            WL.App.close();
        }
    });
    var collectionNameRegistration = 'Registration';
    registerUserFirst(collectionNameRegistration);
}
```

Currently the application gets closed, if invalid SIM is there or if no data is present. The problem is that first the splash screen is seen for some time and then the app gets closed.

But here, I want to close the app immediately when I click on the application icon if invalid SIM is there or if no data is present. 
So where should I place this code snippet to achieve the desired functionality. Or is there any other way to do so? Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`wlCommonInit` takes place **after** the app has launched and the Worklight and Cordova frameworks were loaded, so that's not the right place.

While the app loads, there is a splash screen...

I think your desired functionality is flawed.
For a user to start an app and just have it closed w/out some notification could mean that app just crashed - you're not going to get positive feedback from your customer base.

Why close the app?

- Start the app with `connectOnStartup: false`, meaning that the app will not connect to the Worklight Server on startup. Check for the network and notify the user appropriately - let the user decide if s/he wants to close the app or not.

If you want to quit the app anyway on launch if the network is not preset or if using some undesired network, you need to do this in Native code.

For example, in Android look at src\com ... yourApp.java, there around the `onCreate` code you need to use native functionality to check for what you want and act accordingly.

- To get an idea of how this can be accomplished in native code, you can look at the following question. It doesn't check for the same, but it's same area: [IBM Worklight - Unable to get network signal strength in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23545039/ibm-worklight-unable-to-get-network-signal-strength-in-android)

If you want to do this in Worklight across your supported environments, you'll need to do this separately for each environment in native code, or... re-consider what you're doing, or do it as you're doing it now.