# IBM Worklight : How to Fetch call logs and contacts?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

Am new to IBM Worklight,Is there a way to fetch the call Log and contact,like in android using `TelephonyManager` to track call duration,call details.Can any one know,please guide me to do fetch these details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worklight itself does not have access to this information. However, Worklight uses Cordova, and using Cordova you could gain this access.

To accomplish the above, you will need to create a Cordova plug-in, from which you will be able to hook into the `TelephonyManager` and retrieve any information that it can provide you, including call duration and details.

Creating a Cordova plug-in cannot be explained shortly, so I will link you to the training module explaining exactly this: [Adding native functionality to hybrid applications with Apache Cordova](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html#GS_native_to_hybrid).

Also, in the following question I have code written that enables hooking to the TelephonyMananger to get a different type of information, so you should be able to modify it to get what you need: [IBM Worklight - Unable to get network signal strength in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23545039/ibm-worklight-unable-to-get-network-signal-strength-in-android)

Comment: Whenever going to access the native details Like call details,SQL Lite,GPS etc.Write the code in Native language to get the details from there using Cordova am right.

Comment: Depends. Some native access can be achieve by using Cordova JavaScript API (refer to the Cordova API website), and others can be accessed by implementing a Cordova plug-in, where you access information using native code.